# Выводит undefined

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

это должен быть задачник в котором что при вызове `render()` что при создании нового элемента выводит в браузер `undefined`

```js
const input = document.getElementById("title")  //input в который вводим новую заметку
const createBtn = document.getElementById("create") //кнопка создающая заметку
const createEl = document.getElementById("name") // li в которую помещаем html

const notes= [
    {
        title: "Write code",
        complete: false
    },
    {
        title:"Learn Js",
        complete: true
    }
]
function getNoteTemplate(notes){
    return`<li">
        <span class="margin-r" >${notes.title}</span>
        <span>
            <span class="spanBtn">&check;</span>
            <span class="spanBtn">&times;</span>
        </span>
    </li>`
}

createBtn.onclick = function(){
    if(input.length ===0){ 
        return
    }
    const newNote ={
        title:input.value,
        complete: false
    }
    createEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
    getNoteTemplate(newNote.title)) // тут undefined
    input.value=" "
}


function render(){
    for(note in notes){
        createEl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
        getNoteTemplate(note)) //тут undefined
    }
}
render()
```

```html
<input id="title">
<button id="create">Создать</button>
<ul id="name"></ul>
```

Comment: `for (note in notes)` для объектов, а у тебя массив, использую `for (note  of notes)` и в строке `getNoteTemplate(newNote.title)) // тут undefined` отправляй объект целиком а не значение свойства title `getNoteTemplate(newNote)) // тут undefined`

Answer (score 2):

При переборе массива - используйте `of`, а не `in` (для объектов)

```
for(note of notes){}
```

И здесь не `getNoteTemplate(newNote.title))`, a

```
getNoteTemplate(newNote))
```

```js
const input = document.getElementById("title") //input в который вводим новую заметку
const createBtn = document.getElementById("create") //кнопка создающая заметку
const createEl = document.getElementById("name") // li в которую помещаем html

const notes = [{
    title: "Write code",
    complete: false
  },
  {
    title: "Learn Js",
    complete: true
  }
]

function getNoteTemplate(notes) {
  return `<li">
        <span class="margin-r" >${notes.title}</span>
        <span>
            <span class="spanBtn">&check;</span>
            <span class="spanBtn">&times;</span>
        </span>
    </li>`
}

createBtn.onclick = function() {
  if (input.length === 0) {
    return
  }
  const newNote = {
    title: input.value,
    complete: false
  }
  createEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    getNoteTemplate(newNote)) // тут undefined
  input.value = " "
}


function render() {
  for (note of notes) {
    createEl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
      getNoteTemplate(note)) //тут undefined
  }
}
render()
```

```html
<input id="title">
<button id="create">Создать</button>
<ul id="name"></ul>
```

Comment: Тэг li нельзя пихать в div